# I need to replace all ü Characters with ue from my Textfile. If Im trying this I get "ou out. How can I remove the " from ou?

Tags: bash, sed, replace, diacritics

I need to replace all ü Characters with ue from my Textfile.

**I tried the following:**

`set -e 's/ü/\"ue/g`

Output: "ue

**If im writing it like this I became E:**

`set -e 's/ü/\ue/g`

Output: E

---

My actual problem is: How can I remove the " from "ue?

Comment: `sed -e 's/ü/ue/g'` - why do you add ``\`` at all? Also, you have a typo in `set`.

Comment: Don't add in the `"` in the first place? Your replacement text is explicitly `"ue` with the leading double-quote.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suppose that your command is

```
sed -e 's/ü/\"ue/g
```

the final command is

```
sed -e 's/ü/ue/g
```

without the backslash